# Change button background from transparent to colored when pressed

Tags: android

I have some buttons with transparent background in my app. Now, I want to customize them to maintain that transparent background, but when they are pressed, the backgroud should become green.

I know that are lots of topics about custom buttons here on SO, I have readed several of them, also lots of tutorials from google. And although it may seem an easy task, I'm not getting it to work.

This is an example code of my buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/accept_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/button_state"
    android:text="@string/btnaccept"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And this is the selector xml file `buton_state.xml` where I've defined the background color change for diferent button states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   

    <!-- Button focused and pressed-->
    <item   android:state_pressed="true"
            android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/LightGreen" />    
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Button Default-->
    <item   android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="false" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This file is in res/drawable folder.

In my app, the button gets correctly a default transparent background, but this background color doesn't change to green when focused nor pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this may be help you,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/LightGreen" /> <!--pressed --> 
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- Normal -->
</selector>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I have tried in a similar way to this and didn't work... but now it is working. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Use Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>
```

and then

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:background="@drawable/Selector File Name"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="126dp"
 android:text="Hello" />
```